# Combine two queries into one with total of each query being its own column

Tags: mysql

I apologize in advance for the rookie question. Haven't used SQL in years and my knowledge is rusty. I'm trying to combine two queries into one but I am hitting a roadblock. Here are the two queries I'm trying to combine.

```
select  ct.name
     , ci.closed
     , COUNT(ci.template) as OPEN
  from ServiceCall sc 
  JOIN Activity ac 
    on sc.id = ac.object.objectId
  JOIN ChecklistInstance ci 
    on ac.id = ci.object.objectId
  JOIN ChecklistTemplate ct 
    on ci.template = ct.id
 where sc.id = 'DAEAFC0E883B464CBDBBD51248AD364F'
   AND ct.name NOT LIKE '%JSA%'
   AND ci.closed = false
 GROUP 
    BY ci.template
     , ct.name
     , ci.closed;
```

The one above gets the count of open items and the one below gets the count of closed items.

```
select ct.name, ci.closed, COUNT(ci.template) as CLOSED
from ServiceCall sc 
JOIN Activity ac on sc.id = ac.object.objectId
JOIN ChecklistInstance ci on ac.id = ci.object.objectId
JOIN ChecklistTemplate ct on ci.template = ct.id
where sc.id = 'DAEAFC0E883B464CBDBBD51248AD364F'
AND ct.name NOT LIKE '%JSA%'
AND ci.closed = true
GROUP BY ci.template, ct.name, ci.closed;
```

The technical challenge I'm having is getting the open and closed results to appear side by side.

[image: Results to 1st query]

[image: Results to 2nd query]

I'm essentially just trying to get a final result with the 'Name', the count of closed (closed = true) and the count of open (closed = false).

Any suggestions or tips would be much appreciated. I'm sure this is a simple solution but I've hit a wall and could really use a nudge in the right direction.

EDIT: I've tried using UNION but I feel like I'm doing something wrong. Specifically, I just tried running a UNION by combining both queries and it seems to combine the results of both the COUNTs into one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    ct.name
    , ci.closed
    , SUM(IF(ci.closed = true, 1, 0)) AS CLOSED
    , SUM(IF(ci.closed = false, 1, 0)) AS OPEN

FROM ServiceCall sc 

JOIN Activity ac ON sc.id = ac.object.objectId
JOIN ChecklistInstance ci ON ac.id = ci.object.objectId
JOIN ChecklistTemplate ct ON ci.template = ct.id

WHERE sc.id = 'DAEAFC0E883B464CBDBBD51248AD364F'
AND ct.name NOT LIKE '%JSA%'

GROUP BY ci.template, ct.name, ci.closed;
```

I've removed the where clause on `ci.closed` and added two new columns with SUM IF for both.

Comment: @charjun I'm happy I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a CASE expression:

```
select ct.name, ci.closed, SUM(CASE WHEN ci.closed = true THEN 1 END) as CLOSED, SUM(CASE WHEN ci.closed = false THEN 1 END) as CLOSED
from ServiceCall sc 
JOIN Activity ac on sc.id = ac.object.objectId
JOIN ChecklistInstance ci on ac.id = ci.object.objectId
JOIN ChecklistTemplate ct on ci.template = ct.id
where sc.id = 'DAEAFC0E883B464CBDBBD51248AD364F'
AND ct.name NOT LIKE '%JSA%'    
GROUP BY  ct.name, ci.closed;
```

Answer (score 1):

A Simple IF Statement would help here:

```
select ct.name, ci.closed, SUM(IF( ci.closed = true,1 ,0)) as CLOSED, 
SUM(IF( ci.closed = false, 1,0)) as OPEN
from ServiceCall sc 
JOIN Activity ac on sc.id = ac.object.objectId
JOIN ChecklistInstance ci on ac.id = ci.object.objectId
JOIN ChecklistTemplate ct on ci.template = ct.id
where sc.id = 'DAEAFC0E883B464CBDBBD51248AD364F'
AND ct.name NOT LIKE '%JSA%'    
GROUP BY  ct.name, ci.closed;
```

The IF statement means that When `ci.close = true then return 1 Else return 0`